# How to change a gtkSlider color and size in CSS for python glade object?

Tags: python, css, gtk3

I have tried using: background, size, width and min-width, height and min-height but none seem to change the bars color for example if value is 0 to 100 and it is at 50, half of the bars highlighted color should turn red where scale is the gtkscaler object and videoScaler is my specific instance of the gtkscaler.How to change a gtkSlider bar color and size in CSS for python glade object? For example, the purple part of the image to red or what ever color.

```
scale#videoScaler{
color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
border-color: rgba(251,188,20,1);
background-color: lightgrey;
box-shadow: -80px 0 0 80px #43e5f7;
}
#I found this out after the fact it changes the size of the slider center piece and the bar but does not change the color of the bar
scale slider{
  
  border-color: rgba(251,188,20,1);
  background: rgba(251,188,20,1);
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

[this pic is what the above code looks like]

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

To change the slider bar (officially called a "trough"), you can use the `scale trough` class. For changing the color of the trough's "empty" half (the gray part of the bar in your image), you can set the `background` attribute of `scale trough`, like this:

```css
scale trough {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

To change the color of the "full" half (the purple part of the bar in your image), you need to use the `scale trough highlight` class, like so:

```css
scale trough highlight {
    background: #00ff00;
}
```

If you use the both of the code snippets above in your CSS file, the first half of the trough should be bright green, and the second half should be red. Of course, you can change the colors, and yes, you can use `rgba()` instead of the hex colors if you want.